# Java CompletableFuture get Method

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I am having some trouble understanding CompletableFuture. I do not understand the get() method. Please correct me if I am wrong, but it says 
"Waits if necessary for this future to complete, and then returns its result." So If I do not return any result I do not have to call get method?
Please see below. Even I do not call get() method it still does its job. So I understand get() as if the future returns something it will make sense then, otherwise get() is not necessary for a future that does not return anything.

```
//Since it does not return something two statements below do the same thing.

CompletableFuture.runAsync(doSomething()); 
CompletableFuture.runAsync(doSomething()).get(); 

private final CompletableFuture<Void> doSomething() {
 //do something 
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of get() is to wait for the task to complete, then return the result.

If your task is a [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), not [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), it will return a Void, so as you have pointed out, there is no point in checking the result. For such tasks you are executing get() only to **wait for them to complete**.

The main advantages of CompletableFuture are the methods that allow you to handle exceptions, and further process the data. It also has methods wo wait for [all and single](https://medium.com/@senanayake.kalpa/fantastic-completablefuture-allof-and-how-to-handle-errors-27e8a97144a0) task to complete from a set of ComplatableFuture tasks. So it's mutch easyer to work in multithread anv. `get()` method works same as for [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) class though.

UPDATE:

If you don't require for them to complete before passing further in your application, you don't have to call get() method at all. But it would be wise to keep a reference to them, and wait for them to complete or cancel them before exiting a program. At some point of the program you probably will want to see if they have completed.

But if you want for the to complete before going further, then you can use `CompletableFuture.allOf()`.

In some cases it's also wise to add a timeout to their execution, so that you will not have a hanging thread in your application. This may be dangerous, especially on mobile environment.

So it all depends on your business case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, "wait for them to complete." If I do not require it to be completed before I continue the application. I do not have to call the get() on it? Does it mean I should call get only if I wanna complete  that future before I continue?

Comment: @nalala Do you know any method where it is different? Each method has a purpose. If you don’t need it, don’t call it.